# Can I return to the UK if my Tier 2 visa expires in less than 2 days?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

Hi I am in UK for 1 year ICT tier 2 visa. I got. Schengen visa valid from April to Sep 25. My UK visa ends by Nov 25,2016.

I heard I cant come back to UK next time, if I travel to any Schengen country and not return before 3 months of UK visa expiry.

Say suppose, if I go to France by Sep 10 and return Sep 15(valid schengen visa period) to UK. Sep 15 is not with in 3 months of UK visa expiry Nov 25.

If I do like this I won't be eligible to come back to UK next time may be year or later. Is there any such rules are available? Googled a lot and coudnt get clear picture on this.

Not sure I can book a trip or not.

Comment: Where did you hear that you can't reenter the UK within three months of your visa expiration? It doesn't seem like a very credible claim.